# For all real numbers satisfying $a < b$, there exists an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a + 1/n < b.$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, real-numbers

From Stephen Abbott's *Understanding Analysis 1.2.11*:

> For all real numbers satisfying $a < b$, there exists an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a + 1/n < b.$

My try:

$$\forall a\in \Bbb R, \forall b\in \Bbb R, \exists n \in \Bbb N \space \text{that satisfies}: \space a<b \Rightarrow a+\frac 1n<b$$

$\because a<b $

$\therefore\exists m\in\Bbb R, m>0$ such that $b=a+m$.

So the statement we are proving becomes (substitute $b$ by $a+m$):

$$\forall a\in \Bbb R, m \in \Bbb R, \exists n\in\Bbb N \space \text{that satisfies}: a<a+m \Rightarrow a+\frac 1n < a+m$$

Which is (take $a$ from both sides):
$$\forall m\in \Bbb R, \exists n\in\Bbb N \space \text{that satisfies}:0<m \Rightarrow \frac 1 n<m$$
We write this as: $$\forall m\in \Bbb R, 0<m, \exists n\in\Bbb N \space \Rightarrow \frac 1 n<m$$

We define set $M = \{m\mid M=\Bbb R \cap m>0\}$

And set $N = \{\frac 1n \mid n \in \Bbb N\}$

$\because\forall q \in \Bbb Z, p\in\Bbb Z, \frac p q\in\Bbb Q$

$\space\space\space n\in\Bbb N\subset\Bbb Z$

$\therefore\frac 1n\in\Bbb Q$

Mention that $m\in\Bbb R$

$\because\Bbb Q\subsetneq\Bbb R$

$\therefore\forall n\in\Bbb N, \exists m \in \Bbb R \Rightarrow \frac 1n \geqslant m$

This statement is equivalent to:
$$\forall m\in \Bbb R, 0<m, \nexists n\in\Bbb N \space \Rightarrow \frac 1 n<m$$

Which disproves the statement, which is wrong - What is wrong with my disproof?

Also, I am learning how to use mathematical notations properly (because I am only in year 11 but anyway). Please tell me if there is any error in my expressions.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Some errors I caught as of now is the statement $\forall p,q \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $\frac pq \in \mathbb{Q}$. This is not true, consider $p = 1$ and $q = 0$. The second error I see is that $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{R}$ a proper subset does not imply your second last statement. This has to do with density of $\mathbb{Q}$ \in the reals, which in simple terms states that for any 2 real number, there is a rational in between. In particular $0$ and $m$ are real numbers so there must be a rational in between

Comment: It is quite hard to read what you have written. Take a look at this article for some guidelines on writing mathematics: https://math.hmc.edu/su/wp-content/uploads/sites/10/2020/08/Guidelines-for-Good-Mathematical-Writing.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your eagerness to make things formal (*very* formal), you've ended up juggling a bit too many entities. :)

So if I understand correctly, you're saying that the statement from Abbott's textbook should be true, whereas you found a proof that it isn't. Informally, your argument seems to boil down to something like this:

> I have to show that, given $m\in\mathbb{R}$, $m>0$, there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$, such that $\frac{1}{n}< m$. But it also holds that, for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, I can always find an $m\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\frac{1}{n}\geq m$. So Abbott's statement is false.

I guess the misunderstanding comes from using the same symbol '$m$' to refer to what are two distinct numbers.

First off, let's check that the original statement is indeed true. As Ethan mentions, your chain of reasoning (with the $m$ and the sets $M$ and $N$) is a bit overkill. More simply, just notice that the inequality you start with can be rewritten as $n>\frac{1}{b-a}$. In other words, you have to show that for any $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $a<b$, there exists an $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n>\frac{1}{b-a}$.

Since $b-a>0$, it is not difficult to see that this, in general, true. As an example, suppose $a=0.02$ and $b = 0.34$ (I chose these numbers at random). Then $\frac{1}{b-a} = 3.125$. Can we find a natural number greater than $3.125$? Yes: $4$ works; $5$ works; anything greater than $5$ also works. Broadly speaking, no matter what $a$ and $b$ you start with, the bag of natural numbers is large enough that you can always find some $n$ that is large enough and that fits your needs.

This is just to give some intuition for why the original statement is true.

Now coming back to your proposed answer, I would say the last inference is a mistake. Indeed, for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there exists $m\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\frac{1}{n}\geq m$. That is to say, given $n\in\mathbb{N}$ you can always find *some* very small $m$, smaller than $\frac{1}{n}$. But that doesn't mean that you've disproven the original statement, because this $m$ is not the same as the $m$ you've started with! It's a different $m$, which, to avoid confusion, should probably not even be denoted $m$ in the first place. Perhaps if you give it a different name, say $r$, it becomes clearer that from the last statement you introduce it does not follow that you've disproven the original claim.

Answer (score 4):

Part of an answer, too long for a comment.

Your very last statement is true: for every positive real number $m$  there is some integer such that $1/n < m$.

How you know that statement is true depends on what axioms for the real numbers you start with. One common axiom is that for every real number $r$ there is some integer $M > r$.

I think you are creating problems for yourself by thinking that proper mathematics uses lots of symbols. Words are almost always easier to understand and to write. The *idea* behind this assertion is that no matter how small $b-a$ is there will be a unit fraction smaller still, since the fractions $1/n$ are smaller and smaller the larger $n$. Just turn that idea into words:

> Suppose $a < b$. Then $b-a > 0$ so there is an integer $n$ such that
> $1/n < b-a$. Then the result follows from simple algebra.

If you need to go all the way back to the Archimedean axiom

> Suppose $a < b$. Then $\frac{1}{b-a} > 0$ so there is an integer $n > \frac{1}{b-a} $  Then the result follows from simple algebra.

Answer (score 0):

I think your proof is OK up to the point I write below. Here's a typical trick in doing these things. To prove that:

$\forall m \in \mathbb{R}$ where $m > 0$, then $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $\frac{1}{n}<m$.

You want to fix an arbitrary $m > 0$ and show there exhibit some $n \in \mathbb{N}$  so that $\frac{1}{n} < m$, and think about why that is sufficient! Proving this actually requires the Archimedian property, which says for the reals:

$$
\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \text{ there is a } n \in \mathbb{N} \text{ so that } n > x
$$
and proving this requires the least upper bound property of reals.

Also, with the archimedian property, you can rather shortly conclude the proof.